# fix RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /agents/ error in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, crm

i am creating a django CRM website  but i a have a problem once i want relate the User to an organisation.

**Note :
the user must be logged in in order to be able to create agent**

## model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)# every USER has one profile
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Agent(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)# every agent has one user
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    # create signal to listen to event in order to create a profile user once a new user is created.
def post_user_created_signal(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user = instance)

post_save.connect(post_user_created_signal,sender=User)
```

## views.py

```
class AgentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView)
    template_name = "agent_create.html"
    form_class = AgentModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("agents:agent-list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        agent = form.save(commit=False)
        agent.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
        agent.save()
        return super(AgentCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

once the user try to create an agent this error below is displayed.

> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /agents/
>
> User has no userprofile.
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/agents/
> Django Version:   4.0.6 Exception Type:   RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
> Exception Value:
>
> User has no userprofile.
>
> Exception Location:   C:\Users\LT
> GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py,
> line 461, in **get** Python Executable:   C:\Users\LT
> GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe Python Version:
> 3.10.4 Python Path:
>
> ['F:\DJANGO',  'C:\Users\LT
> GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
> 'C:\Users\LT GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
> 'C:\Users\LT GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
> 'C:\Users\LT GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
> 'C:\Users\LT '
> 'GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages',
> 'C:\Users\LT '
> 'GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32',
> 'C:\Users\LT '
> 'GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
> 'C:\Users\LT '
> 'GM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
>
> Server time:  Sun, 17 Jul 2022 18:54:40 +0000

Comment: Did you inspect the data? Is it possible that for some of the old data the user doesn't have the user profile? You can easily check it using the django shell

Comment: this was the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem string is here:

```
agent.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile
```

The `self.request.user` has no `userprofile` yet.

Perhaps you need to change the logic in your code.